# How to calculate explicitly the *external leg correction* diagram

Tags: homework-and-exercises, quantum-field-theory, feynman-diagrams

I tried to calculate the Amplitude of the *external leg correction* of figure 6.1 in Peskin & Schroeder.

I focus on the diagram with one incoming charged fermion $f^-$ (with momentum $p'$), then a loop with a virtual photon (integrating over momentum $k$). After this a vertex with an emitting photon (momentum q) and the outgouning fermion $f^-$
with momentum $p$. Momentum conservation says $q=p'-p$

My problem is: When I write the propagator of the fermion $f^-$ between the loop and the emission of the photon, its momentum is well known $p'$ and on-shell and therefore the propagator has a infrared divergence.
An other divergence which can be handled with Pauli-Villars regularisation comes from the loop.

Is this correct so far? How to handle the divergence coming from the on-shell propagator?

Comment: Note that, whether or not actual homework, this question is homework-like since it just asks for the way to carry out a calculation, and is thus likely off-topic [under the homework policy](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/q/714/50583).

Comment: This is a question to a general problem. I only mentioned this case as an example to illustrate what I was wondering about.